# Is this a restrictive appositive?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure what to make of this sentence I came across:

> Reviewing the employee roster, Murphy began choosing whom to let go. **Mr. Cottard, I will need him to return his keys**.

"Mr. Cottard" is not a direct address; it refers to "him". It does not conform to the general rules of a restrictive appositive since it begins the sentence and has a comma, but it does provide essential information. Of course, it could be rewritten as "I will need Mr. Cottard to return his keys."

Comment: No, not an appositive. As JK2 says, this is an example of "left dislocation", where the personal pronoun "him" has "Mr Cottard" as antecedent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the phenomenon is called "dislocation", and specifically "left dislocation":

Here's a quote from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by H&P (Page 1408):

> A dislocated clause has a constituent, usually an NP, located to the left or right of the nucleus of the clause, with an anaphorically linked pronoun or comparable form within the nucleus itself. Compare, for example, the non-dislocated [1i] with the two dislocated versions given in [1ii–iii]:
>
> [1] i *Her parents* seem pretty uncaring. [non-dislocated version]
>
> ii *Her parents*, *they* seem pretty uncaring. [left dislocation]
>
> iii *They* seem pretty uncaring, *her parents*. [right dislocation]
>
> In [i] *her parents* is functioning in the nucleus of the clause (in this case as subject), with no element external to the nucleus. In [ii–iii], by contrast, *her parents* stands outside the nucleus, to the left and right respectively, and the coreferential pronoun *they* occupies the place filled by *her parents* in the non-dislocated version.